# Can't get selected option in controller

Tags: spring, select, amazon-s3, controller, thymeleaf

I have a form to list up buckets in select options, it uploads file to bucket after select bucket and file, but I can't get selected bucket in my controller, The folder alwsy return empty string, though mutipartFile is no problem, I really want to know why! 
I googled for all this week but no result what I need! 
I am very new in thymeleaf even in spring framework:( 
Pls help me to solve this simple problem to you:)

part of html file as below:

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" th:object="${folder}" th:action="@{'/drill/skin/upload'}" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-static">Select Bucket</label>
    <select class="form-control" th:field="${folder}">
      <option th:each="bucket : ${buckets}" th:value="${bucket.name}" th:text="${bucket.name}">bucket</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label class="form-control-static" for="inputSuccess">Select Upload   File</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="uploadFile"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary center-block" type="submit">Upload</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

controller as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String provideUploadInfo(Model model) {
  List<Bucket> buckets = s3Service.listBuckets();
  model.addAttribute("buckets", buckets);
  model.addAttribute("folder", "com.smartstudy");
  return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(
  @ModelAttribute("folder") String folder,
  @RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile uploadFile, Model model) {
  log.info("Bucket: " + folder + ", uploadFile: " +   uploadFile.getOriginalFilename());
  if (!uploadFile.isEmpty() && !folder.isEmpty()) {
    return s3Service.upload(uploadFile, folder);
  }
  return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your code.

Ideally, the whole form should be encapsulated in one form-backing object. In your case, create a Java object that wraps the folder and the file together.

```
class BucketFileForm{

    private MultipartFile uploadFile;
    private String folder;

    public String getFolder() {
        return folder;
    }
    public void setFolder(String folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }
    public MultipartFile getUploadFile() {
        return uploadFile;
    }
    public void setUploadFile(MultipartFile uploadFile) {
        this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
    }
}
```

Make this object available in the model so that you can access it in the  view

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String provideUploadInfo(Model model) {
    List<Bucket> buckets = s3Service.listBuckets();
    model.addAttribute("buckets", buckets);

    //replace this
    //model.addAttribute("folder", "com.smartstudy");

    //with
    BucketFileForm bucketFileForm = new BucketFileForm();
    bucketFileForm.setFolder("com.smartstudy");
    model.addAttribute("bucketFileForm", bucketFileForm);

    return "index";
}
```

Now, use this form-backing object in the form

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" th:object="${bucketFileForm}" th:action="@{'/drill/skin/upload'}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-static">Select Bucket</label>
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{folder}">
            <option th:each="bucket : ${buckets}" th:value="${bucket.name}" th:text="${bucket.name}">bucket</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <label class="form-control-static" for="inputSuccess">Select Upload   File</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" th:field="*{uploadFile}" class="form-control" name="uploadFile"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary center-block" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then modify your POST endpoint to accomodate these changes.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(@ModelAttribute("bucketFileForm") final BucketFileForm form, final BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    log.info("Bucket: " + form.getFolder() + ", uploadFile: " +   form.getUploadFile().getOriginalFilename());

    if (!form.getUploadFile().isEmpty() && !form.getFolder().isEmpty()) {
        return s3Service.upload(uploadFile, folder);
    }

    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Great! You are right, one form with one form class is simple to do anything else!